# Why isn't this camera following the path it's constrained to?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints, path

I'm trying to constrain this camera to a curve, but it flies off the path.

[image: The camera clearly isn't following the path.]

Here's what the camera's constraint modifier looks like:

[image: A screenshot of the camera's Follow Path constraint.]

You can find the .blend file [here!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ax35IIKCKurnRxNnbAHwvYz8B-rH7deI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Without checking the file, I'm quite sure you haven't reset the camera's location and rotation...?

Comment: Please show all keyframes of the location, or other modifiers of the camera.  If the camera is stationary on the origin (0,0,0) you will achieve better results.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann [here's](https://i.imgur.com/ec6Ezb9.gif) what the camera movement looks like with its location reset.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger [here](https://i.imgur.com/7iK33KL.png) are the camera constraint's keyframes! an influence of 0 at frame 0 and an influence of 1 at  frame 240. when i reset the camera to 0,0,0, [this](https://i.imgur.com/ec6Ezb9.gif) is the result.

Comment: @MEATTAIL Yeah well, what do you want the camera to do? Follow the curve exactly? Then the influence has to be 1 all the time. 0 means stay at original position, 1 means follow the curve exactly. Every animated value inbetween means mix the position on the curve with the original position.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i've got it! looks like i just got the influence confused with the offset factor. i've set the influence to always be 1 and keyframed the offset factor.

Comment: @MEATTAIL But you're aware that there is an animation on the _Evaluation Time_ on the curve as well, don't you? Under _Path Animation_ in the _Curve Properties_. The _Evaluation Time_ also makes the camera move along the curve, and with the _Offset_ you can adjust how much ahead or behind the camera is in relation to the path animation.